# Can anyone identify this IC on an RGB cross-fading circuit?

Tags: led, integrated-circuit, identification, circuits

[image]Q1 is an IC. I just used that symbol as a placeholder. So all this chip does is gradually brighten and dim each of the LED lines, in overlapping intervals. So red brightens, then as red dims, green brightens, then as green dims, blue brightens, and so on. The IC receives a constant 12 V. There is no part number on the IC and I've replicated the board perfectly in the schematic.

Edit: theres another resistor from pin 1 to pin 4.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Likely a microcontroller.

Comment: Do you have an image of the IC of interest? It may have had its markings removed which would indicate the manufacturer wanted to obfuscate the part number intentionally.

Comment: It could be a Microchip PIC part or a Picaxe part (e.g., https://picaxe.com/hardware/picaxe-chips/picaxe-08m2-microcontroller/), or "other".

Comment: _"The IC receives a constant 12 V"_ - What is the power supply voltage? Could the diode between pins 1 and 8 be a Zener? What value and voltage rating is the capacitor?

Comment: Can you post a photo of the IC?

Comment: @BruceAbbott adding

Comment: it could be a zener. I just threw together a quick schematic with taking values into account. Seems like the chip does something really simple.

Comment: Is the 10k resistor below the IC connected to pins 4 and 8? Please measure the voltage between pin 1 and 8 when it is operating.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [PIC 12F675](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MCU08/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/41190G.pdf) and similar series, power on pin 1, ground on pin 8, I/O on the rest.

Looks like they're just using something like that and pulse width modulating the outputs for dimming.

Answer (score 1):

No way to know for sure, but I'm going to guess a PIC12F508-E/P -- Pin 1/8 as V+ and V- is a very "microchip" thing to do.

https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/PIC12F508

Answer (score 0):

I would guess it’s an ASIC, a very simple one with an oscillator and sone digital logic. There are a lot of such LED driver chips from relatively unknown makers for high volume things like novelty flashing LEDs, Christmas etc lights, flashlights, bicycle lights etc.